# Perl printf of colored text - wrong format output

Tags: perl, printf

I have this issue, that when I use colored text, the printf formatting (aligning) is not correct.
In this example, notice how the last column is 1 space to the left.
Searching for a solution only tells me that it, most probably, has to do with the escape sequence in the color variables in the code.

it there a simple solution for this issue, or do I need to add code to add a space when the text is colored ??

The code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };
use Data::Dumper;

# Color variables
my $DEFAULTCOLOR = "\e[0m";
my $RED = "\e[31m";
my $GREEN = "\e[32m";
my $YELLOW = "\e[33m";
my $BLUE = "\e[34m";
my $MAGENTA = "\e[35m";

my %HeartbeatHash = (
'BOTH' => [ '-', 0, '-', 10 ],
'PTN' => [ '-', 0, '-', 10 ],
'PKT' => [ '-', 0, '-', 10 ],
);

printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-s\n", "Heartbeat", "Counter", "LastRun", "TriggerTime");
printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-d\n", "NOCOLOR", ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[3]});

${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}++;
${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]} = "Passed";

printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-s\n", "Heartbeat", "Counter", "LastRun", "TriggerTime");
printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-d\n", "NOCOLOR", ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[3]});

${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}++;
${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]} = "${GREEN}Passed${DEFAULTCOLOR}";

printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-s\n", "Heartbeat", "Counter", "LastRun", "TriggerTime");
printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-d\n", "GREEN", ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[3]});

$DEFAULTCOLOR = "\033[0m";
$GREEN = "\033[32m";

${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}++;
${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]} = "${GREEN}Passed${DEFAULTCOLOR}";

printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-s\n", "Heartbeat", "Counter", "LastRun", "TriggerTime");
printf ("%-9s %7s %-7s %-d\n", "GREEN", ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[1]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[2]}, ${HeartbeatHash{'PKT'}[3]});
```

The output (the terminal shows the text 'Passed' in green for the last 2 lines:

```
Heartbeat Counter LastRun TriggerTime
NOCOLOR         0 -       10
Heartbeat Counter LastRun TriggerTime
NOCOLOR         1 Passed  10
Heartbeat Counter LastRun TriggerTime
GREEN           2 Passed 10
Heartbeat Counter LastRun TriggerTime
GREEN           3 Passed 10
```

Comment: You'll find [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the colour codes separately so they aren't included in the length calculation by `printf`:

```
my @heartbeats = (
    { color => 'GREEN',
      code_before => "",
      code_after => "",
      counter => 1,
      last_run => 'Passed',
      time => 10 },
    { color => 'GREEN',
      code_before => $GREEN,
      code_after => $DEFAULTCOLOR,
      counter => 2,
      last_run => 'Passed',
      time => 10 },
);

printf "%-9s %7s %-7s %-s\n", qw( Heartbeat Counter LastRun TriggerTime );
for my $heartbeat (@heartbeats) {
    printf "%-9s %7s %s%-7s%s %-d\n",
        @$heartbeat{qw{ color counter code_before last_run code_after time }};
}
```

Also, using [Term::ANSIColor](http://p3rl.org/Term::ANSIColor) would simplify the code and prevent accidental typos in the ANSI colour sequences.

Comment: Thanks @choroba.

Fighting a bit on how to comment in less than the allowed characters..

Comment: Thanks @choroba.

Fighting a bit on how to comment in less than the allowed characters :-) And the return key makes life difficult.

What if you change 'color => 'GREEN' to 'server => 'HOST1' and 'server => 'HOST2' and in the next heartbeat I need to increment the counter and modify the 'last_run' value for each server value?

It is just that this is part of a greater plan and I use the %HeartbeatHash to keep track. I would need to change that only to put some color in the output.

Comment: I think that's irrelevant to the question. You can insert the colours into the hash, or deduce them from the status, the point is not to concatenate the colour codes with the value to be printed, but to print them as separate `%s` items.

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant to the issue, but relevant to the solution, hence my followup question
But this is probably seen as a different topic and not in the spirit of stackoverflow.
My first topic on stackoverflow, so still learning.

Comment: I didn't want to design the data structure for you, so I used a simpler one. Now it's upon you to decide whether you want to include the colour ANSI sequences in the hash, or derive them from the values before printing.